# Count number of Rows after applying Filter ClosedXML

Tags: vb.net, closedxml

How to count number of Rows after applying a filter in Closed XML

Code : ws.AutoFilter.Column(5).AddFilter("xval")

```
   xRow=ws.usedrange,rowcount()
```

Now xRow won't give us the number of rows after applying filter . It gives the count of all row.

Can anyone provide any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you type wrong? because there is a coma after `usedrange`
The corret code is `xRow=ws.usedrange.rowcount()`

Comment: Sorry, That was a typo. I used xRow=ws.usedrange.rowcount(). But gives count of total rows. Once you apply filter some rows will get hidden. But it gives the count including the hidden rows

Comment: yes it does, `usedrange.rows.count()` gives you the number of all used rows, hidden ones included. At this point, try to save inside a variable how many rows you hidden with the filter and than try to do this:
`xRow=ws.usedrange.rowcount() - hiddenRows`